# Why can't I supply a sum of two strings as an argument to a constructor that takes a string?

Tags: c++, constructor

To better explain, I have the following constructor in class Card:

```
Card(std::string& s);
```

Therefore it only needs one string to create a Card object. However in another file where I have another class called Deck, which is derived from class Card, this class roughly looks like this:

deck.h:

```
class Deck : public Card
{
  Card deck[52]; //this will hold 52 cards

};
```

deck.cpp:

```
Deck::Deck()
{
  std::string value[13] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
  std::string suit[4] = {"H", "D", "C", "S"};
  int k = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
      //std::string str = value[j] + suit[i];
      //deck[k] = str; //CREATES ALL 52 CARDS //<---INSTEAD OF DOING THIS
      deck[k] = value[j] + suit[i]; //<---WHY CAN'T I SIMPLY DO THIS
      k++;
    }
  }
}
```

Its just a simple question I am just curious as to why its so pedantic, because a sum of two strings is one string, so it should work.

Here is the error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Card’ and ‘std::basic_string<char>’)
       deck[k] = value[j] + suit[i];
```

Comment: A `Card` is not a `std::string`.  Also, the error shows this as an assignment going on, `error: no match for ‘operator=’ ` not a construction, so the constructor does not come into play.

Comment: Why is `Deck` a derived class of `Card`? Doesn't make much sense

Comment: Your inheritance for `Deck` just seems wrong to me. A deck is not a card.

Comment: Well I have just started writing programs with classes, so I am not very good, my idea is to create a deck of 52 card objects, therefore to create a deck I need to tell the program what a "card" is.

Comment: You've already constructed your deck array.  Your class has no provisions on assigning a string to an already constructed `Card`. Yes, you can *create* a `Card` from a string, but your current class lacks any means of taking an *existing* `Card` and give it a string.

Comment: So I should make an array of 52 strings and then construct cards from those? I apologize for being slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your constructor takes a non-const reference. [Non-const references cannot be bound to temporary values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/10077). You should make your constructor accept a const reference.

```
Card(const std::string& s)
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you, although I still am not sure as to why it must be const

Answer (score 0):

First of all prefer `std::array<>` over legacy C-Arrays:

```
class Deck : public Card {
  std::array<Card, 52> deck; //this will hold 52 cards
};
```

Now to your question:

```
Card(std::string& s);
```

here s is an lvalue-reference to a string.

```
deck[k] = value[j] + suit[i]
```

C++ will generate a temporary string which holds the value `value[j] + suit[i]`. That can not be a lvalue-reference, because a lvalue-reference parameter is expected to be used after the call. The temporary can not be used, because it is a temporary. Therefore the standard just does not let you do that.

In case the lvalue-reference is const, it is obvious, that the referenced object can not be changed inside the function. Therefore the C++ standard allows you to pass a temporary as well.

So the solution is to use

```
Card(const std::string& s);
```

With C++11 you can also use the rvalue-reference to move the string into your new object instead of copying it:

```
Card(const std::string&& s) :
  name_{std::move(s)} {};
```

Here the temporary string will be passed by reference. The move cosntruction of the member variable `name_` will simply "steal" the memory that contains the string from the passed parameter, so that the string is never copied.

Comment: That is nicely explained thank you, I had to look up what is exactly meant by an lvalue, I think I get it now.